# Switch statement vs seperate function calls for performance

Tags: c++, performance, virtual-machine

I am writing a virtual machine and the main loop looks something like this:

```
while (running)
{
    switch (get_opcode())
    {
        case 0x00: some_instruction() break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Some instructions have a similar function, for example: **cast_32** and **cast_64**. So I thought of two options:

1. Create a separate function for each one of them

```
// vm's main loop
switch (get_opcode())
{
    case X: some_instruction_version_x() break;
    case Y: some_instruction_version_y() break;
}

...
// implementations of instructions

void some_instruction_version_x()
{
    // do something
}

void some_instruction_version_y()
{
    // do something slightly different
}
```

2. Use the same function but with a switch statement inside of it

```
// vm's main loop
switch (get_opcode())
{
    case X: some_instruction(some_enum::X) break;
    case Y: some_instruction(some_enum::Y) break;
}

...
// implementations of instructions

void some_instruction(some_enum version)
{
    // do something that both versions have in common

    switch (version)
    {
        case some_enum::X: /* do x specific things */ break;
        case some_enum::Y: /* do y specific things */ break;
    }
}
```

While I think that version 2 looks 'cleaner' I am a bit worried that the switch statement in second option would affect performance considering this is a vm and this code can run very frequently.

So my question is - which option is better and would the switch statement in option 2 actually affect performance or would the compiler maybe optimise it and split it into two functions by itself?

Comment: Why two switches, can't the first function just do `some_instruction(get_opcode())`?

Comment: It will not visibly affect the performance, and in some cases might even be optimized-away. Don't bother yourself with pre-mature optimization, write the code that best expresses what you need. And since it looks like your machine is using some kind of mapping "code --> function", then you might consider using `std::unordered_map<Code, Function>`

Comment: @pptaszni why not normal map?that would be faster lookup if there are many options. For two options idt doesn't matter if it's just an `if()`

Comment: Sounds like it's time to (re-) invent  interpreter and strategy design patterns.

Comment: Contrary to all the comments and answers so far, you should avoid function calls and nested `switch` statements altogether in interpretive loops. Put the code inline in the `case` statements as far as possible. The overhead in interpreters is everything that isn't devoted to executing the instruction, which includes function-call overhead, switch statement overhead, &c.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie , because `std::unordered_map::at` is on average O(1); Not that it matters that much, but `std::map` for me carries additional information (which is not true in this case): "I want my elements ordered". Then why not simple `if`: because it is cleaner to write `_map.at(opCode()).execute();`. O, I see you already mentioned interpreter - yes, this is the way (but maybe for later).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I thought the common wisdom is that hash maps are better (even though the standard one is suboptimal). Their downside is that they're susceptible to hash collisions on bad input.

Comment: @user207421 Can't I just make the functions 'inline'? I think the switch statement would get quite big if i implemented over 200 instructions there

Comment: If you make `some_instruction()` to accept what's returned by `get_optcode()` (instead of a `some_enum`), you could remove the useless second `switch statement`, which is basically redoing a branching that has been already done at the upper level. But, if you are to handle a lot of `case`s (like the `200` mentionned earlier), maybe having a separate function for each case could be easier to maintain than a mega-big function containing everything in it.

Comment: If you do not do measurements you are not doing performance improvements, but just do guessing. This is depended on so many factors that any claim may look logical, but be completely wrong. Only performance measurements has a final word. Please see this [cppcon where similar issue is addressed](https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg?t=1876).

Comment: @Fareanor I've updated the question, using result of get_opcode() as an argument would not make the second switch useless

Comment: @Daniel It will indeed get big. You could try inlining, but if you're after the ultimate in performance you will sweat over every processor cycle, especially those in the interpreter's fetch and decode cycles.

Answer (score 4):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. If I were writing this code, I would take a different road:

Implement `some_instruction_version_x()` and `some_instruction_version_y()` so that both call `some_code_common_to_both()`, and that way you do not have to write it twice. Note that the main benefit is simplicity and clarity - it is way too soon to worry too much about runtime.

Once your code works, compile it with optimizations enabled, and then **run it through a profiler using a representative workload** to find hot spots. The hot spots are the important part to optimize - everything else is probably not worth it.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil": this is a partial quotation. Have a look at what Knuth *actually* said, and note that it applies precisely to this situation.

Comment: @user207421 Actually it's the real quote. Just belonging not to Knuth but to Sir Tony Hoare. Knuth was quoting and added own concerns\interpretation.

Comment: Actually it is a partial quotation. There is more. Look it up. It also remains to be shown that this is a case of *premature* optimization, which it isn't, analytically.

Comment: @user207421 "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"? I have that hanging on the wall in the office

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie That is exactly what I am referring to, and why what is stated in this answer is a partial quotation.

Comment: @user207421 why not write out an answer spelling out the importance (and expected advantages) of optimizing in this particular case, if you really feel it to fall into Knuth's critical 3% of optimizations that you should not pass up upon? I believe such gains to be minimal, and also compiler in-lining and optimizations may make many changes to code moot.

Comment: @tucuxi I've given my reasons in other comments.

Answer (score 1):

> While I think that version 2 looks 'cleaner' I am a bit worried that
> the switch statement in second option would affect performance
> considering this is a vm and this code can run very frequently.
>
> So my question is - which option is better and would the switch
> statement in option 2 actually affect performance or would the
> compiler maybe optimise it and split it into two functions by itself?

There is no simple proper answer for that.

Remember that C++ compilers are using ["as-if rule"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), as a result such simple tweak you are proposing can be completely transparent for final machine code (compiler may decide to inline all your small functions).

Predicting what compiler can optimize, how hardware can interact which code, is really really hard. As a result only reliable way to improve performance is some kind automated performance measurements.

Knowing what compiler and hardware do is just a guide what else can be change in implementation which could improve results, but final  decision must be taken based on measurements.

Take a look on this [cppcon where performance is optimized for very similar scenario](https://youtu.be/IAdLwUXRUvg?t=1876).

Answer (score 0):

If X and some_enum::X version 2 is not good because you do twice the same switch test, just write some_intruction(get_opcode()).
If X and some_enum are different, version 2 is ok. Switch performance cost depends on the type you test, **if it is a simple enum the performane cost is negligible**.

Using version 1 or version 2 depends on the specific instructions.
If code is factorisable (like you suggest) AND the meanings of some_instruction() is the same in any case use version 2

Comment: I've edited my question, it was supposed to be some_enum::X and some_enum::Y in the second switch

Comment: ok if it's about simple enum, don't worry about performances (whatever the compiler optimize or not), just write the clearer code for a human.